# apt-get command does not work on Ubuntu-On-Windows / Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, apt-get, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed [Ubuntu-On-Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/06/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14316/) recently added on Windows 10 for peoples on the fast ring. However, when trying to install new applications using `apt-get`, the command seems to fail everytime. I'm getting this error:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

I know this is a beta and has just been released, but is there a fix for that out yet?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To fix the issue, I ran the following command:

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

And now it works fine, even if I close and re-open the terminal.

Comment: Did you intentionally mean to do `update` twice, or is the latter supposed to be `upgrade`?

Comment: @vcsjones you were right, I made a typo when re-writing the command here. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, you may need to add **sudo** before this command, but it does seem to do the trick or run **sudo -s** to become root before using it, like I did to make it work on my system

Comment: No need to do apt-get upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a problem of `/etc/resolve.conf.` The latest Windows Update fixes this problem, so you can try updates.

Answer (score 4):

Found out that AVG explicitly has a toggle for allowing/disallowing firewall access to Ubuntu. 
Turns out you have to go into 
`Firewall > Advanced Settings > Expert Settings > Advanced Settings > Allow any traffic of Windows subsystem for Linux`.

Just documenting this in case someone else is looking for this one little checkbox, like I spent hours doing.

Comment: It seems that this option is
only available on Windows 10, OS build 14328 and later

Comment: Anyway, I can't find this checkbox

Comment: found this in Jan 2020, turning off windows defender while executing 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.                                                            Need to get 0 B/148 kB of archives.                                                                                                       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.  
installed ok, no errors but 0 installed.
sudo apt-get update
failed while defender  was off.
Version 1903 (OS build 18362.535)

Answer (score 3):

Check your Windows or Antivirus Firewall setting. You may need to disable it in order to allow network connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and found that all networking was disabled. Turning off my bitdefender firewall allowed everything to work as expected. The standard windows firewall switched on automatically on doing this.

I found this [post](https://forum.bitdefender.com/index.php?/topic/70640-sent-to-devel-firewall-prevents-networking-from-windows-10-new-bash-shell-2/) that indicates bitdefender 2017 has fixed the issue, and evidence of [other AV products](https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?showtopic=354919) having similar issues but  for me I'm happy with the windows firewall and Bash on Windows is working well.

Answer (score 1):

I faced an issue where running `sudo apt-get update` does not show any sort of network activity and closed with the same error. **Running the bash as an administrator** solved this problem for me.